# write a program to test numbers whether its prime or perfect

Tags: java

```
public class assignmentno7
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        long i,c1=1,n;
        for(n=1;n<20;n++)
        {
            for(i=1;i<(n+1);i++)
                if(n%i==0)
                    c1+=i;
            if(c1==1) 
                System.out.println(n+"is prime");
            else if(c1==n) 
                System.out.println(n+"is perfect");
            else 
                System.out.println(n+"its a regular number");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to write a program that test number whether its prime or perfect
I have no errors is my program 
but im not getting the right solutions

this is my output :

```
----jGRASP exec: java assignmentno7

1its a regular number
2its a regular number
3its a regular number
4its a regular number
5its a regular number
6its a regular number
7its a regular number
8its a regular number
9its a regular number
10its a regular number
11its a regular number
12its a regular number
13its a regular number
14its a regular number
15its a regular number
16its a regular number
17its a regular number
18its a regular number
19its a regular number

 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this because c1 becomes 2 on your first loop and increases from there.  You never have a case where c is less than 1.

Reconsider how you are tracking if a number is prime or not.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your real problem here is not the domain problem at hand, but an lack of understanding about how to discern what your code is actually doing. You're not going to get anywhere if you look at the output, see that it's not correct, and go straight to Stackoverflow for help.

A couple of suggestions.

1. Add System.out.println calls to your code so that you can watch it execute. This is a primitive form of "logging", and it's alright to start out without a full blown framework like log4j.
2. Turn on your debugger. Your jgrasp IDE has a debugger built in so that you can watch the code values as it executes. http://www.jgrasp.org/tutorials187/06_Debugger.pdf
3. Write out an example number that should be prime, and then trace through your code with pencil and paper to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> any suggestions ?

Yea.  Check the definition of a prime number ... and compare it to what your inner loop is actually doing.

And if that isn't sufficient, ask yourself what the value of `N % 1` is, for any `N` greater or equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from 'c1' never being 'c1 == 1' or 'c1 == n'. It seems you've forgotten to wrap your second loop in brackets. This could be the issue because you're trying to increment 'c1' n times before checking it.

Then try to 'println(c1)' to see what's going on with it during your loop.